# why i need these 2 positional argument

Tags: python

```
from cgi import test
from gobblet import Gobblet, GobbletError

class Joueur:
   
    def __init__(self, nom, no_joueur, gobelets):
        self.nom, self.no_joueur, self.piles = self.valider_joueur(nom, no_joueur, gobelets)

    def valider_joueur(self, nom, no_joueur, gobelets):
        self.nom = nom
        self.no_joueur = no_joueur
        self.piles = gobelets
        nom = str(nom)
        no_joueur = [1,2]
        gobelets = [[Gobblet()], [Gobblet()], [Gobblet()]]
        if gobelets == [[]]:
            return []

        if len(self.nom) == 0:
            raise GobbletError("Le nom du joueur doit être une chaine de caractères non vide.")

        if self.no_joueur not in range(0,3) :
            raise GobbletError("Le numéro du joueur doit être 1 ou 2.")
        
        if type(gobelets) != list:
            raise GobbletError("Les piles de gobelets doivent être spécifiés sous la forme d'une liste.")

        if len(gobelets) != 3:
            raise GobbletError("Le joueur doit posèder 3 piles")
        
        if len(self.piles) != 2 or None:
            raise GobbletError("Une pile doit être une liste de deux entiers ou une liste vide.")
        
        return (nom, no_joueur, gobelets)

test = Joueur('nelson' , 2, [[1, 1], [], [1, 2]])
print(test.valider_joueur('nelson', [], [[1, 2], [1, 2]]))
```

My code always make this error

```
TypeError: Gobblet.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'grosseur' and 'no_joueur'
```

Comment: Check the documentation of the `Gobblet` class to see the arguments required.

Comment: Apparently, the `Gobblet` class's constructor requires at least two positional arguments, just as the error says.   You are attempting to create a `Gobblet` by calling its constructor without any arguments.   This is the problematic line: `gobelets = [[Gobblet()], [Gobblet()], [Gobblet()]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are invoking `Goblet()` with no arguments and they are not optional:

```
gobelets = [[Gobblet()], [Gobblet()], [Gobblet()]]
```

Do something like

```
gobelets = [[Gobblet(grosseur, no_joueur)], ...
```

providing `grosseur` and `no_joueur` are defined.